# How to understand ' Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space of functions $f$ : $ \mathcal{X} \rightarrow R$, denoted on a non-empty set $\mathcal{X}$.'

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning

I am a beginner. By asking this question, I means that, to construct a Hilbert space, should $\mathcal{X}$ satisfy some properties? Furthermore, in some papers especially on machine learning, statistic, and optimization, many problems are formulated on an observed finite data set $\mathcal{Z}$, and the final mathematical results lie in a Hilbert space (e.g., kernel regression), then how should I believe that $\mathcal{Z}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{X}$ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Definition

Comment: @Jihad , thank you, but it is too long to catch the point...

Comment: Usually in machine learning or statistics $\mathcal{Z}, |\mathcal{Z}| = \ell$ is some element from $\mathcal{X}^\ell$ and "Hilbertability" of $\mathcal{Z}$ follows from the fact that $\mathcal{X}$ is a Hilbert space. In fact from the space of functions to be a Hilbert space it is necessary to define scalar product on functions and to assure that this space will be full.